# ¿Por qué al querer mostrar los productos en el DOM recorriendo el array arroja undefined?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, dom, innerhtml

En este proyecto quise crear un div con información de productos (ramos de flores) y no toma los valores del array, es decir, arroja undefined. El problema debe estar al recorrer el array y querer pintar en el DOM los productos (tiposRamos) pero no hallo cómo descubrir el punto del problema.

```
const Stock = {
  rosas: 100,
  azucenas: 50,
  helechos: 80,
  hojas: 30,
}

class Ramos {
  constructor(id, nombre, precio, tiene) {
    this.id = id
    this.nombre = nombre
    this.precio = precio
    this.tiene = tiene
  }
}

class Contenido {
  constructor(rosas, azucenas, helechos, hojas) {
    this.rosas = rosas
    this.azucenas = azucenas
    this.helechos = helechos
    this.hojas = hojas
  }
  modificarStock() {
    Stock.rosas -= this.rosas
    Stock.azucenas -= this.azucenas
    Stock.helechos -= this.helechos
    Stock.hojas -= this.hojas
  }
}

const cantidadFlores = []
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(6, 0, 2, 1))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(12, 3, 4, 2))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(0, 6, 3, 2))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(3, 3, 2, 1))
console.log(cantidadFlores)

const tiposRamos = []
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(1, 'Simple', 500, cantidadFlores[0]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(2, 'Extra', 1000, cantidadFlores[1]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(3, 'Elegante', 1300, cantidadFlores[2]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(4, 'Fresco', 800, cantidadFlores[3]))
console.log(tiposRamos)

let ramoElegido = 0
function ingreseRamo() {
  ramoElegido = Number(
    prompt(
      'Ingrese el ramo que desea comprar:' +
        '\n' +
        '1)Simple \n2)Extra \n3)Elegante \n4)Fresco',
    ),
  )
  while (ramoElegido < 1 || ramoElegido > 4) {
    ramoElegido = Number(
      prompt(
        'Ingrese el nombre de un ramo válido:' +
          '\n' +
          '1)Simple \n2)Extra \n3)Elegante \n4)Fresco',
      ),
    )
  }
  return ramoElegido
}

ingreseRamo()
console.log(ramoElegido)
let content = cantidadFlores[ramoElegido - 1]
console.log(content)

content.modificarStock()
console.log(Stock)

let ubicar = document.getElementById('ubicado')

for (tipo of tiposRamos) {
  let mostrarRamos = document.createElement('div')
  mostrarRamos.innerHTML = `
<p>${tiposRamos.nombre}<p/>
<p>${tiposRamos.precio}</p>
<p>${tiposRamos.tiene}</p><br>

`
  ubicar.appendChild(mostrarRamos)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema lo tienes exactamente donde creías, al recorrer y pintar el array.

Para recorrerlo estás usando `for (tipo of tiposRamos) {` que es válido para poder recorrer cada objeto de tu array. El problema se encuentra a la hora de querer acceder a la propiedad de cada objeto para pintarla. Para hacerlo estás usando `${tiposRamos.nombre}` pero `tiposRamos` es el array que estás iterando, no el objeto por lo que al tratar de acceder a `tiposRamos.nombre`, por ejemplo, estás intentando acceder a un atributo de un array, y estos no tienen. (si accedieses a `tiposRamos[0].nombre` si que podrías acceder desde `tiposRamos` pero no es lo que te interesa).

A lo que tienes que acceder es a `tipo`, ya que contiene cada objeto del array que estás iterando.

```js
let tiposRamos = []

tiposRamos.push({nombre: 'Rosas', precio: '100', tiene: 'SI'})
tiposRamos.push({nombre: 'Margaritas', precio: '200', tiene: 'NO'})
tiposRamos.push({nombre: 'Violetas', precio: '50', tiene: 'NO'})

for (tipo of tiposRamos) {
  let mostrarRamos = document.createElement('div')
  mostrarRamos.innerHTML = `
    <p>${tipo.nombre}<p/>
    <p>${tipo.precio}</p>
    <p>${tipo.tiene}</p><br>
    `
  ubicar.appendChild(mostrarRamos)
}
```

```html
<div id="ubicar"></div>
```